# Deploy app from CircleCI with

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I'm looking to automatically deploy my app once we release a new version. We use CircleCI, so firing these commands shouldn't be a big deal.

```
cf login -a https://api.lyra-836.appcloud.swisscom.com -u myuser -p seret
cf push myapp
```

However I don't want to expose my personal credentials (Passeport acount) into our git repository. Is it possible to generate an API key for that purpose?

How do you handle that? I might also need to ssh into the instance to fire some migrations scripts after the deployment, same goes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Swisscoms Application cloud does not offer technical accounts but you can create an additional account easily. Then add it to your org/space as developer and it should be able to fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 2):

CircleCI documentation has a section about handling secrets: [Using CircleCI Environment Variables](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/environment-variables/#setting-environment-variables-for-all-commands-without-adding-them-to-git)

> Setting environment variables for all commands without adding them to
> git
>
> Occasionally, you’ll need to add an API key or some other secret
> as an environment variable. You might not want to add the value to
> your git history. Instead, you can add environment variables using the
> Project settings > Environment Variables page of your project.

This documentation describes how to [store encrypted stuff within your VCS](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/environment-variables/#keeping-encrypted-environment-variables-in-source-code).

> If you prefer to keep your sensitive environment variables checked
> into git, but encrypted, you can follow the process outlined at
> [circleci/encrypted-files](https://github.com/circleci/encrypted-files).